# Размещение <div> по центру

Tags: html, текст, позиционирование

Возможно ли разместить  `<div>` по центру,а текст в нем выровнять по левому/правому  краю?

Конкретнее:

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <p> </p>
</div>
```

Как сделать `<p>` по левому краю в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

Блок позиционируете с помощью margin: auto, а текст в нем - как обычно.

```html
<div style="margin: auto; width: 50%; background: yellow;"><p style="text-aligh: left;">text</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Текст выравниваем с помощью `text-align: left`, а `<div>` с помощью `margin: auto`

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <p>Текст</p>
</div>
```

Comment: первый раз задаю тут вопрос,не могу понять как разместить хтмл код.В моем вопросе он есть,но не отображается

Напишу его на русском)

див класс= текст центр
<п></п>
див

в такой ситуации ксс не работает,так как у дива приоритет выше

Comment: Добавил код в ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если у `div'а` не задана ширина - он займет всю возможную область, если задана:

```
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left
```